# Finding an imprimitive group on $12$ letters

Tags: group-theory, permutations

By definition a permutation group $G$ acting on a set $\Omega$ is called **primitive** if $G$ acts transitively on $\Omega$ and $G$ preserves **no** nontrivial blocks of $\Omega$. Otherwise, if the group does preserve a nontrivial block then $G$ is called **imprimitive**.

Here I am asked to find an imprimitive permutation group $\Omega$ acting on $\Omega$ with $|\Omega|=12$ such that $|G|$ be of maximum possible order.

It would be difficult and unprofessionally finding a group which has a block for example with two elements. At least I cannot do that right now. :). Clearly, our $G$ is a proper subgroup of $S_{12}$ but would not be $A_{12}$.

I am wondered how can it be shown that any group I found is of maximum order. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might want to consider the size of the smallest nontrivial block - what does "nontrivial" mean, and why?

Comment: @MarkBennet: The non-trivial blocks are $\Omega$, $∅$ and the singleton sets.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on terminology here. Are we looking for a transitive group? I mean, primitivity/imprimitivity is kinda meaningless, if the group is not transitive, right?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Yes. I am looking for a transitive group, of course.

Comment: Then go with Jack Schmidt's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: given a particular block $B$, consider the group $H_B$ of all permutations that preserve $B$.

Comment: You mean; $H_B=\{\pi\in S_{12}|B^{\pi}=B  or B^{\pi}\cap B=∅ \}$ would be the group?

Comment: @BabakSorouh: yes, but you can describe the group a little more explicitly in terms of those two pieces: Sym(B) wr Sym({B^pi : pi in Sym(Omega).  The first part swirls the elements of a block, the second part swirls the set of blocks, without "changing the blocks inside".  It has order $(m!)^n n!$ where $m=|B|$ and $mn=12$.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Isn't the group in your comment $(S_m×...×S_m).S_n$? Because, I see the order above.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Thanks for your nice illustrating comment.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks for the hint. :)

Comment: @Babak: exactly.  "wr" is just shorthand for what you wrote